# Implementing a Text change event from an Array

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to change textbox fore and back colors of multiple textboxes based on a value if any one of the textboxes change it's value either by user input or reading from the DB.

I am not sure how to implement the code once an individual textbox has a change. The below code is as far as I got as I do not know how to implement it to work. Can someone assist?

```
Private Sub DiffCalcColor_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbPMDiffCalc.TextChanged, tbLHDiffCalc.TextChanged, tbRFDiffCalc.TextChanged, tbFSDiffCalc.TextChanged, tbFSADiffCalc.TextChanged

        Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

        Dim text = tb.Text.Replace("$", "")

        Dim number As Decimal

        Decimal.TryParse(text, number)

        Select Case number
            Case < 0D : tb.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
                tb.BackColor = Color.White
            Case > 0D : tb.ForeColor = Color.Green
                tb.BackColor = Color.White
            Case = 0D : tb.ForeColor = Color.DimGray
                tb.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Case Else
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is `InitializeComponent()` doing there?  That should be called in the Form's Constructor (`Public Sub New()`) and nowhere else. The array also, probably, unless you create the array later, based on some conditions. You should pass the array to the method anyway. What is `key` for? You never use it. -- You need to subscribe to the TextChanged or Validating event of those TextBoxes, to parse the text as - I assume - a decimal value, unless `value` comes from another source. -- You should describe how this thing should work, in your view (where and when these values are generated).

Comment: That code is completely wrong and not what I instructed in my answer. What would be the point of using `AddHandler` to attach a method to an event when you're already inside that method handling that event? Look at the code in my answer and do what I showed you. get rid of the loop andf the `AddHandler`. Cast the `sender` as the appropriate type and then us the result. It IS the object that raised the event so you only care about the value IT contains

Comment: Apart from that, you're not getting the value from the control anyway. Where in that code are you using any `Text` property? You're not, so how could the value of a `Text` property matter? Think about what you are doing. I have already shown you exactly what to do to get the relevant control. Think about what you need to do with/to that control. You need to get the `Text` from it, test that value and then colour the control based on that, right? So why would you think not getting the `Text` was a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle the same event for multiple controls with a single method then you simply include all those controls in the `Handles` clause, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged,
                                                                            TextBox2.TextChanged
    Dim eventRaiser = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    'Get the text that just changed.
    Dim text = eventRaiser.Text

    Dim number As Decimal

    'Try to convert it to a number.
    Decimal.TryParse(text, number)

    'Use the number to decide how to format.
    If number = Decimal.Zero Then
        '...
    Else
        '...
    End If 
End Sub
```

You can do that manually or you can let the designer do it for you. To do the latter, start by selecting the multiple controls in the designer, then open the *Properties* window, click the *Events* button on the toolbar, then double-click the appropriate event. That will generate an event handler, much like double-clicking on a single control does, but it will add all the selected controls to the `Handles` clause. It also allows you to generate a handler for any event, rather than just the default event. To add a control to that `Handles` clause, you can select one or more controls, select the event and then select an existing event handler from the drop-down.

Comment: Updated original code: now all I get is a value of '0' returned under values thus the code is not seeing something >0 and coloring the text per the Case select statement. I'm missing something yet and not sure what it is.

Comment: I'm giving up on this.. I just do not comprehend the program speak very well & I have tried everything I can think of, spending many hours to meet the reqs set forth above, scoured the internet & I am literally brain locked.. Call me thick headed or an idiot... I am just not grabbing the concept and beyond frustrated trying to do as I am trying to do. I am not one to ask someone to write code for me as I learn nothing but this time, I'm thinking that is what I should do but I will not do or request it here especially. Thx for trying to teach an old man something new. Call this a complete bust.

Comment: @K3JAE, it's pretty simple stuff. The problem is that you're trying to go straight from an idea to code. That's not the way to program. Start by forgetting about code. Imagine that you had to do it manually. How would you do it? Thin about the steps involved. I'm sure that, if you wouldn't try to use data without getting it first. Think about the logic and write it down with pen and paper. Break down the steps and formalise them into an algorithm. Once you have that, the code you write should implement that algorithm specifically so you always have something to compare to. See additional code.

Comment: OK, The issue I am continually running into ((not really the coding side) is it is taking a textbox containing "$3.625" (as an example including the "$") and it's failing to convert to 3.625 even with text.trim (aka drop the "$"). Currently it is only converting to "0" (assuming because it sees the "$" and it cannot convert "$" to a number) thus regardless of what actually is in the textbox, it views it as a "0".

Comment: This is why you need to read the documentation. The `Decimal.Parse` and `Decimal.TryParse` methods both allow you to specify various aspects of the allowed input. They both have a parameter of type `NumberStyles` and, if you're trying to convert currency, you would specify `Currency` as the style. If you had searched the web for "vb.net convert currency string to number" or the like then you'd have found direction too. If you are having an issue and haven't read the appropriate documentation or performed the obvious web search then may have spent time but you haven't really tried.

Comment: OK, I've done a bit more studying and playing around and finally found a resolution, that works and does as I hoped. If there is a 'cleaner' way then I'll entertain any ideas. I _now_ understand what I need to do and where I went awry so I can utilize the knowledge for later code I may write in the future.